# Error when opening TIFF from GCS using geemap : Unsupported BitsPerSample and SampleFormat values: (64, 1)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, geemap, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have 1 band image saved on GCS.
The image has 1 band and was saved locally with cog driver and then uploaded to the GCS. In addition, the band is binary - has only 2 values - either 0 or 1 (mask).

I'm trying now to open it using geemap :

```
path_mask_gcs='gs://my_bucket/Reut/my_image.tif'
img1 = geemap.load_GeoTIFF(path_mask_gcs)

img1.getInfo()
```

But I get an error:

> EEException: Image.loadGeoTIFF: Failed to load the GeoTIFF at 'gs://my_bucket/Reut/my_image.tif#1673770842800979': Unsupported BitsPerSample and SampleFormat values: (64, 1)

As I mentioned, The image was saved locally as cog before uploaded to GCS, using the following script

```
   with rasterio.open(savedir /tiff_name, 
                                   'w',
                                   driver='cog',
                                   height=img.shape[0],
                                   width=img.shape[1],
                                   count=1,
                                   dtype=img.dtype,
                                   crs=rasterio.crs.CRS.from_dict(init='epsg:4326'),
                                   nodata=None,
                                   transform=img.transform) as dst:
        
                    dst.write(img, 1)
```

And image is successfully opened on QGIS.

I have also tried to save the image as uint8 but that gave the same error.

How can I open my image using loadGeoTiff? What is the reason for the error?

I have also tried to open it with Rasterio and it works with Rasterio, no errors. But I still need to read it with Geemap.

Comment: That worked. I changed the type before saving it as rasterio and now it opens with GEE. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 64bit datatype and it seems like `geemap` doesn't support that bit depth.

Since you only have a binary 0, 1 raster you can use a byte (uint8) data type:

```
img = img.astype('uint8')
with rasterio.open(savedir /tiff_name, etc...) as dst:
    
                dst.write(img, 1)
```